# Rea XML files in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I have an xml file with the following data

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NAMEDAYS.xsd" generated="2012-08-16T21:47:41">
    <NAMEDAYS>
    <DAY>1</DAY>
    <MONTH>1</MONTH>
    <NAMEDAY>New Years Day</NAMEDAY>
    </NAMEDAYS>
    <NAMEDAYS>
    <DAY>6</DAY>
    <MONTH>1</MONTH>
    <NAMEDAY>Holly Spirit</NAMEDAY>
    </NAMEDAYS>
```

The first element is the day then the month and finally the holiday.
I want to search the xml file for a specific day and month and return the holiday of that date.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you have to create a sample class( for ex: MySampleClass) which will be used to store the XML element values and then you need to filter the data in a similar way:

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("CustomData.xml");
var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("NAMEDAYS")
            where c.Attribute("DAY").Value == "1" && c.Attribute("MONTH").Value == "1"
            select new MySampleClass()
            {
               //set your properties here

            };

listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```